# Send email on button click directly from server, not user client

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

Is there a way to send an email from my mailserver to my own email address when the user clicks on a button?

I don't want a mail client of the user to pop up like it would when using `mailto`.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Because I have no idea at all if this is possible and if so how, I currently got no code. It would be great if you can push me in some directions so I can do more research for specific topics.

Comment: You can call your backend server API on button click and do whatever processing and sending mail you need to do on your server side

Comment: You need a backend for this, like PHP or node for instance. Most webhosts support PHP, and they might have set up your environment accordingly, meaning you can simply use [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to send it. On the client side, you need something like `fetch('/sendmail.php?pick=1')` when the user clicks the button. Note that for a poll you might consider using a database instead of evaluating dozens/hundreds of emails per hand.

Comment: If it's a poll why not just put a link to a survey site on your site?

Comment: It's not really a survey. Poll was the easiest way to explain it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use third party service, such as mailchimp [1], to achieve email sending, without the need for your own dedicated backend system.

Most services offer comprehensive sdk which can be used to send emails. If you google `services similar to mailchimp`, you find multiple blog posts about the topic, such as [2] and [3]. Note, some of these services have free tiers, some do not. Some are better than others in some aspects.

- [1] https://mailchimp.com/
- [2] https://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/best-mailchimp-alternatives/
- [3] https://moosend.com/blog/mailchimp-alternatives/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server side backend for this application, then you can bind a service api and call it via jquery or javascript.

Also if you have a database for this application you can send emails via database server as well.

DB servers such as Sql server, Mongidb have their own email services.